# Display information about a git commit 'without diff' but 'with' files

Tags: git

I have gone through quite a few variations of this question on SO and documentation and the closest command is `git show --quiet` and `git log --name-only -1 -U`

`git show --quiet` does not show the modified/added/removed/renamed files.

`git log --name-only -1 -U` is very close to what I need, it shows the commit details similar to `git show` in addition to the files changes. But it just shows the files changed (and without colour coding). It does not show whether the file was added/modified/renamed/removed.

Is there a command that can show the commit details + files added/modified/renamed/removed but without the diff? This is in hopes to remove my dependence on a GUI tool to go through each commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `--name-status` instead of `--name-only`, it does exactly that.

Look at the doc [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---name-status).

(That being said, and as a sidenote, you don't need `-U` here, since `--name-status` or `--name-only` are preventing diff output anyway.)

I'd just do

```
git show --name-status
```

Comment: thanks, that's almost exactly what I was looking for - any chance of it being colorized as well? the options that I am seeing in the documentation seem to be only for the `diff`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not aware of a way to have these colorized like in `git status -s`, but I'd love to find one too.